# Stitch video with blender to make a 360 video

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm looking to use blender to stitch together multiple videos in order to create a 360 video. How would I go about doing this in blender? Just to be clear I'm not looking to render a 3D scene in 360 but rather take multiple videos taken from different angles and stitch them into a single 360 video.

Comment: You could project each camera onto the inside of a sphere, use masks on the video textures to hide overlapping edges. But you wont get quite the right distortion.

Comment: @3pointedit that's actually an interesting idea. I'm not sure how well that'd work but it's interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible.**

Here is a google search for possible free alternatives, I cannot, however recommend any of them: [free 360 video stitching software](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20360%20video%20stitching%20software)

Comment: Yea...my biggest problem is I haven't found anything that runs on Linux.

Comment: Dual boot with windows, or try using wine. Maybe you could try using Hugin to do the alignment, and then custom code to project and stitch the video.

Comment: :/...I've been avoiding that but it's not looking like I have a choice.

Comment: In fact, if you have the yaw pitch roll information (which can be gathered from one still image, using Hugin or PT Gui), blender could do the distortion and blending.

Comment: Yea I actually installed hugin but I haven't played around with it much.